# How to update to CentOS 7.3 1611 from 7.1.1503?

Tags: centos, operating-systems, yum, centos-7

How to update to CentOS 7.3 1611 from 7.1.1503 ? can it done through yum if yes, how to do it ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? CentOS has good and thorough documentation available online: have you read this yet?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67672/can-i-yum-upgrade-to-a-specific-centos-version